# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lokio/ForwardingTimeout

Tags: java, android, retrofit, okio, okhttp

I am using a android project as library, which are using the following library added as a jar

```
okhttp-2.2.0.jar
okhttp-urlconnection-2.2.0.jar
okio-1.2.0.jar
retrofit-1.9.0.jar
```

And in my main project I am using the following library

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
```

And there are some other library, but after some research I have found that these are causing the problem.

The app runs fine, but crashes with the following error when I tried to consume any web service using retrofit

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lokio/ForwardingTimeout

In my app level gradle file I have added

```
multiDexEnabled true
```

Also I tried adding

```
configurations{
    all*.exclude module: 'okhttp-2.2.0'
    all*.exclude module: 'okio'
}
```

And I tried adding retrofit gradle dependency like following

```
compile ('com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0') {
    exclude group: 'okio'
}
compile ('com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0') {
    exclude group: 'okio'
}
```

None of these worked, my project was working fine before adding the library project. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: For test case , comment lib calling and set `compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'`

Comment: thanks for your response, I tried but didn't work

Comment: `compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.5.0'` . i guess its a mismatched versions problem

Comment: tried but no result